# How does Darth Vader breathe?

Tags: star-wars

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Darth Vader’s suit waterproof?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24464/is-darth-vaders-suit-waterproof)

Does Darth Vader's mouth piece act as an air filter, or an air supply? Basically, if he were under water or out in space, would he still be able to breathe?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Is Darth Vader's suit waterproof?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/24464/2565)

Comment: @Thaddeus: While I used almost the same words as the automated comment; I didn't VTC. That question is quite close, but it's not *actually* a duplicate. It asks a different thing.

Comment: In and then Out.. repeat.  Or that's what I recall from his schematic...

Answer (score 1):

It **can** act as an air supply, since Vader's suit was meant to act as a space suit (e.g. when he crossed from Star Destroyer to rebel blockade runner in SW:E4-ANH).

Obviously, it can ALSO act as an air filter, since he breathes for long time in atmosphere without needing to change oxygen tank or whatnot.

Answer (score 1):

His suit was basically an iron lung: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Vader%27s_armor